# remove nested property value from object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a nested object as follows.

I am looking to remove the img property from it.

```
const myOriginalObject {
    props : {
        isMobile: true,
        data: {
            id: '',
            header: '',
            flag: '',
            desc1: '',
            desc2: '',
            logo: {
                src: '',
                alt: '',
            },
            img: {
                src: '',
                alt: '',
            },
        }
    }
}
```

It works if I do the following.

```
myOriginalObject.props.data.img = undefined;
```

But I looking for a cleaner way to do this rather than setting the value to undefined.

Looking to use unset from lodash.

But it doesn't unset and img value is still there. Can I know what I am doing wrong pls?

```
  import unset from 'lodash/unset';
  // none of following works. 
    
  unset(myOriginalObject, "img");
  unset(myOriginalObject, myOriginalObject.props.data.image);
  unset(myOriginalObject, myOriginalObject.props.data.image.src);
  unset(myOriginalObject, myOriginalObject.props.data.image.alt);
```

Comment: from [the document](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#unset) you need to pass in (array of) string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator.

`delete myOriginalObject.props.data.img;`

Answer (score -1):

You could use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), then you could delete like that:

```
delete myOriginalObject.props.data.img
```

or

```
delete myOriginalObject["props"]["data"]["img"]
```

Comment: it's a valid point. Still a comment is useful. (personally I think 5 min is small enough to consider parallel written answers though) (and this answer provide another syntax)

Comment: I'm not sure why my comment was removed. Just for completeness, [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67974577/remove-nested-property-value-from-object/67974654?noredirect=1#comment120145738_67974654) was for downvote without comment.